# when I pressed the login button without entering username & password, browser's top left corner display message like this "Invalid Info"

Tags: javascript, php, html

when I pressed the login button without entering username & password, browser's top left corner display message like this "Invalid Info" because I didn't write any js code or php code for validation.I want to know how to remove this when I clicked the login button.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please write some code for understanding. First learn how to post a Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do tho but maybe display a simple alert ?

```js
  function showAlert(){
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<body>
<input type="button" value="ClickMe" onClick='showAlert()'>
<div id="dialog" title="" style="display: none;">
  <p>Alert box. wrong username password!.</p>
</div>
 
</body>
```

Comment: thank you very much @tarek.it's what i want actually.

Comment: @NadeeshanBuddhikaJayakodi If this helped you solve your problem you might want to consider accepting it as an answer

Comment: @kerbholz already accepted!